# Windows Phone Orientation Not Working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Orientation code not work but it is correct

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
                {
                    webBrowser1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
```

this is code for application call orientation mode:

```
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged">
```

why?

Comment: Does the orientation stay Portrait? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: after orientation change in landscape, web browser not hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct for orientation

```
if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
            {
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the SupportedOrientations property of the page to PortraitOrLandscape.
Replace the default Grid in the Content Panel section with a ScrollViewer and a StackPanel.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
In detail you will find on same link

Comment: i have changed the property and page on landscape work. MY PROBLEM IS THE WEBBROWSER NOT IDDEN!! IT IS ALWAYS VISIBLE